# How can I redirect one wordpress install to another (both in subdirectories on the same domain)?

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Pulling my hair out over this one.

I have one wordpress install at /2009 and one at /2010. I am trying to redirect all requests to the 2009 site to the 2010 site. I have tried both of these in the root .htaccess and in the /2009 .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^2009.*$ 2010 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^2009.*$
RewriteRule . 2010 [R=301,L]
```

But the 2009 site keeps loading. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to clarify:
You have a wordpress install on the server at /Document/root/2009, viewable in a browser at http://server/2009, and a wordpress install at /Document/root/2010, viewable in a browser at http://server/2010, correct?

The easiest thing to do is login to the server, cd /Document/root and do this:

```
mv 2009 2009.backup
ln -s 2010 2009
```

If you do not have shell access to the server in question, then the second easiest method is to rename the index.php for wordpress in 2009 and load this index.php to it:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://server/2010/"); /* Redirect browser */
exit;
?>
```

Comment: thanks, i was hoping to do it with a line in the .htaccess, since i need to turn the redirect off in a couple weeks, but you are right, I should just do it a different way. no use wasting time on something that's not working! :)

Comment: If I hit the nail on the head, how about some +1 love, eh?

Comment: would if i could, but i don't have the rep requirement yet. need 2 more points!